# Getting rid of a Graph keyword in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this data type :

```
data Node a = Node
    { label :: a,
        adjacent :: [(a,Int)] } deriving (Show, Eq)
data Network a = Graph [Node a] deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I have a function which turns a Graph to a list of nodes :

```
deGraph :: ([Node a] -> Network a) -> [Node a] -> [Node a]  
deGraph _ x = x
 for example : 
Main> deGraph Graph [ ( Node 'a' [ ( 'b' , 3 ) , ( 'c' ,2 ) ] ) , ( Node 'b' [ ('c' , 3 ) ] ) , ( Node 'c' [] ) ]
[Node {label = 'a', adjacent = [('b',3),('c',2)]},Node {label = 'b', adjacent = [('c',3)]},Node {label = 'c', adjacent = []}]
```

But when I use the function inside a function like this :

```
func1 (Graph x) = deGraph (Graph x)
```

I get this error :

> ERROR "./Network.hs":14 - Type error in application
>   *** Expression     : deGraph (Graph x)**
>    Term           : Graph x
>    **Type           : Network b
>   *** Does not match : [Node a] -> Network a

Can you tell me how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `deGraph` function has two arguments and simply returns the second of the two.

You probably want this instead:

```
deGraph :: Network a -> [Node a]
deGraph (Graph x) = x
```

The call to `deGraph` in GHCi works because you forgot to put parentheses around `Graph` and the following list, so it's also a call with two arguments. In `func1`, you (correctly) use parentheses, but then get a type error, because you're inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make `Graph` a record, too:

```
data Network a = Graph { nodes :: [Node a] } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Then `nodes` has type `Network a -> [Node a]`, and can be called like

```
Main> nodes $ Graph listOfNodes
```